# Second level cache parent entity after native delete child with on delete set null

Tags: hibernate, jpa, caching

I'm using the following code to evict cached entities deleted by a native query:

```
 entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict( ChildEntity.class );
```

If this entity type is referenced from other entity **ParentEntity**, what's the behaviour when accesing a **ChildEntity** referenced from a previously cached **ParentEntity**?

**ParentEntity** is the foreign key owner with **on delete set null**, so the child id will be null in database after delete.

I think that the cached **ParentEntity** already knows the old child id, so will it try to get the child entity by id from database and fail? If so, should I also evict all entities that link to **ChildEntity**?

Comment: I ran into a similar issue but then with the eclipselink implementation. If there is a parent object that contains a reference to a child and this child was already retrieved (so not a LAZY relation) then this object is simply there and will be stale if it was e.g deleted in the database. If the parent is also cached and somewhere such an object is retrieved from 2nd level cache, then  the child object will also be there. So caching parent child relations seems a bit tricky. Initially I assumed that evicting parent also would evict the children but this is not the case. I endd up evicting both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing with *Hibernate 5.4.15* it seems that when loading the *Parent* entity from second level cache it will try to load the obsolete child and throw an *EntityNotFoundException* that will cascade and ultimately return a **null** (missing) *Parent* entity, but the *Parent* entity still exists in database.

Opened hibernate bug [HHH-14058](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14058) that contains the sample test repository.